# Seeking better understanding of declaring external javascript modules (writing .d.t.s files)

Tags: typescript

After a bit of trial and error I figured out how to write a .d.ts file for a complex NPM javascript package. The package uses bluebird promises, so it needs to import bluebird and export the bluebird Promise interface. The solution I found boils down to something like this:

```
/// <reference path='../typings/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts' />

declare module 'other' {
  import Promise = require('bluebird');

  interface Foo {
    func1(): Promise<void>;
  }

  var Other: Foo;
  export = Other;
}

declare module Other {
  export module X {
    export interface Y {
      func2(): Promise<void>;
    }
  }
}
```

Nowhere in this file is `Promise` explicitly exported, yet Typescript applications can import this module via a reference path and `import Other = require('other');` and then use the type `Promise`, without even scoping the type as `Other.Promise`.

I've looked through the Handbook and the Language Specification trying to get a better understanding to no avail, though perhaps I've missed something. In seems that `export = <identifier>;` exports more than the identifier. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in [bluebird.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts):

```
declare class Promise<R> implements Promise.Thenable<R>, Promise.Inspection<R>
```

It declares the class in global scope.

Comment: Aha! Since nearly all of my Javascript programming has been with node.js, I tend to forget about global scope.

Comment: Both of the answers here were helpful, but this one was the key insight I was missing for why Promise was available without exporting it.

Answer (score 1):

> Nowhere in this file is Promise explicitly exported, yet Typescript applications can import this module via a reference path and import Other = require('other');

When a file `a` does `/// <reference foo` and later a file `b` does `/// <reference a` then file `b` *implicitly* references `foo`

Here your file references `bluebird` so any thing that `references` your file will implicitly reference `bluebird`.

## Reference vs. import

`/// <reference` *only* works if there is no root level `import` / `export` in the file. If there a root level `export` in the file it is considered an *external module* and can only be brought in with a corresponding `import` in another file.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. But it seems to be inconsistent with the requirement to use the `export` keyword in other contexts. Can you elaborate on this a little?

By the way, Typescript is *awesome*. Thanks!

Comment: @4dan I've added more clarification